# USB device not detected when reset

Tags: c, usb, reset, keil

I have implemented a USB device as a virtual COM (CDC-ACM). I am able to communicate when I download the program on my board and all it is okey, but I detect that when I do a cold reset (power off the board), the PC (host) can not detect the USB, and obviosly my program can not work in USB mode.

```
// INITIALIZE USB DEVICE RUTINE
USBD_Initialize((uint8_t) USB_DEVICE_ID);
USBD_PowerControl(ARM_POWER_FULL);
USBD_DeviceConnect();

// UNINITIALIZE USB DEVICE RUTINE
USBD_DeviceDisconnect();
USBD_PowerControl(ARM_POWER_OFF);
USBD_Uninitialize((uint8_t) USB_DEVICE_ID);
```

I think that when I make a cold reset, I don't let my microncontroller to uninitialize the USB device, and when I try to connect it again the error appear.

Is my theory right?

Has someone any idea about how to implement the solution?

Thank you every one!

BR.

Comment: What happens if you disconnect the board, power-cycle it, and reconnect it? -- Oh, and please make sure you took the [tour] and read "[ask]". Please [edit] your question with new information, don't post a comment.

Comment: As I said, if I power off (or disconnect) the board, the PC doesn't recognized my USB device. I have been watching what happens on the D+ pin, and when I reconnect the board, and reconnect the USB I see that they (PC and device) start to communicate but 1 second later the PC notifies me that it can not recognized the device.

Comment: Well, I asked because there is a difference between disconnect and cold reset. The USB host senses the USB device. -- Would you mind to [edit] your question, please? Additional information tends to get lost in comments. -- So you need to find out why your device is recognized after download, which is some kind of disconnection because your device's software does not run, but not after a later disconnect-reconnect. Do you have a USB analyzer? I never tried, but Wireshark is said to be able to trace USB communication.

Comment: Okey, I will try to use Wireshark to trace the USB communication as you tell me. This project which I am programming has a Cold/Hot reset mode, so I think that when i do a COLD RESET the program take a different way that when I load my program on board.